# rich:popupPanel always show scrollbars

Tags: jsf, richfaces, modal-popup

My JSF form contains a popup panel. The code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>Partner Manager</title>
    <link href="stylesheet/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.png" />
    <script src="script/script.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText id="progress_bar" styleClass="progress-bar" />
    <div id="header">
        <div class="header-content">
            <img src="images/logo2.png" />
            <div class="header-message">
                <p class="links">
                    <a href="#">Sign Out</a>
                </p>
                <p class="welcome">
                    Welcome <label>John Smith</label> <span>Associate Manger</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <h:form>
            <fieldset class="search-area">

                <rich:calendar value="#{partnerBean.selectedStartDate}"
                    datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

                <rich:calendar value="#{partnerBean.selectedEndDate}"
                    datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

                <h:selectOneMenu label="Categories" id="categories"
                    style="width:200px" styleClass="dilevery"
                    value="#{partnerBean.selectedDeliveryMethod}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Type" itemValue="Select Type" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Type" itemValue="Select Type" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Type" itemValue="Select Type" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Type" itemValue="Select Type" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <a4j:commandButton id="searchButton" value="Search"
                    onbegin="showProgressBar();" oncomplete="hideProgressBar();"
                    render="@form,tableDv,transactionTable"
                    action="#{partnerBean.searchPartnersTransactions}"
                    styleClass="search-btn" />

                <a4j:commandLink href="#" styleClass="add-teller"
                    title="Add Partner">Add Partner
                    <rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show" />
                </a4j:commandLink>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="tableDv">
                <rich:dataTable id="transactionTable"
                    value="#{partnerBean.partnerTransactions}" var="transaction">

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Date of Transaction" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.dateOfTransaction}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Transaction ID" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.transactionID}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Recipient name" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.recipientName}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Amount Sent" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.amountSent}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Recipient's Phone No" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.recipientPhoneNumber}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Sender's name" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.senderName}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Type of Delivery Method" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.typeOfDelivery}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Partner Fee" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.partnerFee}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Status of Transfer" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.statusOfTransfer}" />
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
            </div>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="container" style="overflow:scroll">
                <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" autosized="true"
                    resizeable="false" domElementAttachment="form"
                    followByScroll="true">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Process Teller Transaction" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="controls">
                        <h:outputLink value="#"
                            onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">
                        x
                     </h:outputLink>
                    </f:facet>
                    <div id="container">
                        <fieldset class="add-form">
                            <legend>Add Account</legend>

                            <p class="choose-type">
                                <label>Account Type :</label> <select class="account-type"><option>Partner</option></select>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Partner Name :</label><input type="text"
                                    value="Enter Partner Name" class="partner-name" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Email Address :</label><input type="text"
                                    value="Enter Email Address" class="email-fld" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Address :</label><input type="text"
                                    value="Enter Postal Address" class="address-fld" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>City :</label><select class="city-fld"><option>Select
                                        City</option></select>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Partner Limit :</label><select class="limit-fld"><option>Select
                                        Limit</option></select>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" value="Create Account" class="search-btn" />
                            </p>

                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </rich:popupPanel>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="footer-content">
            <div class="footer-liks">
                <a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">Company Profile</a> | <a href="#">Partner's</a>
                | <a href="#">Survey</a> | <a href="#">Jobs</a> | <a href="#">Press</a>
                | <a href="#">Contact Us</a> <span>Copyright © 2012
                    CoinFling.com. All rights reserved. <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                    - <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The popup shows. However, if the content is too large, then the scrollbars do not appear. How do I let the scrollbars always appear when it's required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to set a style on the div?

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="container" style="overflow:scroll"> ... </h:panelGroup>
```

If that works, then the best would be to define a class.

Maybe you also have to explicitly define the size of the popup to get it to work properly.

Update:

The final solution was to use a `<h:panelGroup>..</h:panelGroup>` block inside the `<rich:popupPanel>` without any additional style information. The `<rich:popupPanel>` already renders a div with the `overflow:auto` style around it's content but the size calculation of the popup seems to fail if there is only plain html code inside it.

Comment: I have updated the full page code. My Popup is part of the page. The scoll is added to the page underneath but not to the popup itself. Any help would be nice.

Comment: What i meant was to replace the <div id="container"> by the <h:panelGroup> not wrap the popupPanel itself. The intention is that your popup content get s the scrolling ability. (hint : <h:panelGroup layout="block"> renders a <div>)

Comment: I have done, this. It does work, but there are two scollbars now. I have uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: On the richfaces showcase i saw that the popupPanel itself has a popup_content_scroller-div element, wich already has overflow:auto set. Seems that the plain html inside the popup caused the size calculation to fail. Try to remove the stye from the <h:panelGroup> but keep it inside the popupPanel.