# Is there a way to disable default scrollbar for rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I am using `<rich:popupPanel>` tag,rich:popup panel provides default scroll bar when the data is huge,I am using my custom scroll bar instead of this.
is there a way  to hide the default scroll bar which is provided by `<rich:popupPanel>` tag.

```
<rich:popupPanel id="termEditPanel"
                 followByScroll="true"
                 autosized="true"
                 modal="true"
                 resizeable="false"
                 moveable="false"
                 styleClass="popup term-editor-panel"
                 rendered="#{agreements.agreement.editable}" 
                 zindex="1000">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rich:popupPanel always show scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030998/richpopuppanel-always-show-scrollbars)

Answer (score -1):

you can add next style to page for override native richfaces pop-up style

```
<h:outputStylesheet>
        .rf-pp-cnt-scrlr {
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }
</h:outputStylesheet>
```

or use style

```
<rich:popupPanel id="category"
                     modal="true"
                     resizeable="false"
                     autosized="false"
                     width="300"
                     height="300"
                     styleClass="popUpMain"
                     style="overflow:hidden !important;"
                     domElementAttachment="form"
                     onmaskclick="#{rich:component('category')}.hide()">
```